# Laravel date_format validation failing for HTML input type week

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I got this data from request:

```
{
    "type": "custom",
    "start_week": "2020-W19"
}
```

And my validation rules are:

```
    return [
        'type' => 'required|in:standard,custom',
        'start_week' => 'required|date_format:Y-\WW',
    ];
```

Which gives me this result:

```
"errors": {
    "start_week": [
        "The start week does not match the format Y-\\WW."
    ]
}
```

I used this format before for validating week type input like "2020-W19".

Am I doing something wrong, what can I do?

Comment: Do you have to escape the first W?

Comment: @shaedrich Yeah, otherwise it will get number of the week instead of just the letter; first W is just the letter as in the format, second W is for number of the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it. You'r right. Surprisingly it doesn't work.

But here is a way that you can deal with it. By **Using Closures** and `Carbon` instance directly we can have our own custom rule which works fine:

```
$request->validate([
    'start_week' => [
        'required',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (!Carbon\Carbon::hasFormat($value, 'Y-\WW')) {
                $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
            }
        },
    ]
]);
```

More info : [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, surprisingly and unfortunately. Well, this works nicely but I just want to know if I can do something similar with Rule facade, I have seen its usage for "in" rule.

Comment: Sure you can. We have `rule object ` that give you simple, clean and powerful way to implement your rules. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-rule-objects

Comment: Cool! The only nice and short alternative to these can be using "regex" rule I suppose.

Comment: Yeah exactly :)